# How do I find average price of items within a dictionary if those items are Blueberry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

Use the dictionary, price, defined in the next cell to answer the question. In the next cell, use a for loop to calculate and print the average price of Blueberries.

```
price = {
1: ['Blueberry', 'US', 1.31],
2: ['Pineapples', 'Brazil', 3.71],
3: ['Pear', 'Costa Rica' , 0.58],
4: ['Plum', 'US', 1.00],
5: ['Grapes', 'US', 1.25],
6: ['Papaya', 'Costa Rica', 0.4 ],
7: ['Blueberry', 'Mexico' , 1.58],
8: ['Plum', 'Mexico', 1.50],
9: ['Grapes', 'Italy', 2.25],
10: ['Blueberry', 'Italy', 2.50 ]
}
```

I need to get the average price of Blueberries, but I'm not sure how to get the price from these only if the price is for blueberries.

Comment: Show us your attempt. This is a fairly simple solution if I understood your question right.

Comment: This is  data structure to use Pandas.

Comment: Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results if you follow the advices on those articles.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code. Hope this helps:

```
price = {
1: ['Blueberry', 'US', 1.31],
2: ['Pineapples', 'Brazil', 3.71],
3: ['Pear', 'Costa Rica' , 0.58],
4: ['Plum', 'US', 1.00],
5: ['Grapes', 'US', 1.25],
6: ['Papaya', 'Costa Rica', 0.4 ],
7: ['Blueberry', 'Mexico' , 1.58],
8: ['Plum', 'Mexico', 1.50],
9: ['Grapes', 'Italy', 2.25],
10: ['Blueberry', 'Italy', 2.50 ]
}


average = [ value[2] for key, value in price.items() if value[0]=='Blueberry']

print(sum(average)/len(average))
```

Ouput will be :

```
1.7966666666666669
```

Comment: u can use `[value[2] for value in price.values() if value[0]=='Blueberry']`

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a one-off, you could write something such as

```py
blueberry_prices = [v[2] for v in price.values() if v[0] == "Blueberry"]
avg_blueberry_price = sum(blueberry_prices) / len(blueberry_prices)
```

This uses a list comprehension to extract (from the values in the dictionary) only the prices (list index 2) where the name (list index 0) is equal to "blueberry"

For anything doing this more frequently, you may want to write a generalized function comparing to an input rather than to "blueberry"